# How can i break Pandas Dataframe on bases of time interval

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to break the Pandas Dataframe within some time interval, like I have data for the whole day, and I want to break it into every 5 hour pieces, I have datetime feild as `2016-10-02 12:00:00` to `2016-10-02 24:00:00`

how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using  [Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html), new variable group here split the data frame to 5

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Time':mydates}).reset_index()

df['group']=df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time',freq='5h'))['index'].transform('first')
```

More info

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Time',freq='5h'))['index'].transform('first').nunique()
Out[186]: 5
```

Data Input :

```
start_date = "2017-10-28"
stop_date = "2017-10-29"
mydates = pd.date_range(start_date, stop_date,freq='Min')

df=pd.DataFrame({'Time':mydates}).reset_index()
```

Comment: I need the result something like this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609391/pandas-how-to-split-dataframe-by-column-by-interval/47210634?noredirect=1#comment81370592_47210634   what you gave me the solution, its just dividing the date into 5 hours interval, but I need the whole data in that five hours.

Comment: @Ravi I give your the new column group you can base on this column split the data frame

Comment: Thank you, It worked for me, last time, but what if there is another value, but there is not unit like hour or minute, then this grouper will not work, what I will do in other case?

Comment: data is multiple columns, I have one column values 2,3,5,10, 19,33,34,34,44,56,755,12,10,12,23,45,12,11,4,5,10, suppose this is the column and there is fix value which is dis =10, if any value go below this in the column it will break the dataframe into multiple frames, for above column df[1]= 2,3,5,10 df2 = 19,33,34,34,44,56,755,12 and remaining will be just like the same way

Comment: @Ravi sorry, I still can not get the point ...If you can either change your question or you can post a new one .It is hard to answer in the comments ...

Comment: you can find my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47556251/cumulative-sum-and-breaking-into-different-data-frames-in-python) here on this post. but I don't have to take the sum, have to just find less than value and segment the dataframe.

Comment: here is another [example](https://reformatcode.com/code/python/pandas-splitting-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframe-based-on-threshold-value) which I was looking for, but the given answer doesn't work for me,

Comment: @Ravi adding the answer to your new question, it will not solve by the function .