# cumulative sum and breaking into different data frames in python?

Tags: python, pandas

i have one column Col A in `Python DataFrame`

```
Col A = 0.5, 0.3,1 , 3 , 0.2 , 3, 3, 4, 5
```

and I have one fixed value which is `dis = 4`
I have to take out sum, of col A, if that sum is `greater than the dis` separate those rows, and start the same thing where it ends last like first five rows sum is greater than dis, I break it in different DataFrame, then I have next few rows sum which is == dis and I can break it into different DataFrame until it ends up doing all rows, I know for loop is possible way to do it, but any better solution?

Is it possible to do in Python?

Comment: Do you think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26605026/4819376) can help you?

Comment: @user32185 Thank you, yes this is what I want, but how will I segment the dataframe after that point? any Idea

Comment: @Ravi i don't know about `.ep` an option is to create a similar function that return a key for each group then `list(df.groupby('key'))` will return you all the dataframes (and the key so you should navigate inside the list).

Comment: show you expected out base on your example

Comment: the following answer didn't work for me, I am looking something called .le() and .ge() function, which may work I guess

Answer (score 0):

Let us do following:

```
A=[]
m=0
for y,x in enumerate(df.Col1):
    m+=x
    print(m)
    if m>=4:
        m=0
        A.append(y)
    else:
        m=m

df['g']=np.nan
df.g.iloc[A]=list(range(len(A)))
df=df.bfill()
```

Now you have new column g, then you can split the df

```
[y for _,y in df.groupby('g')]
Out[965]: 
[   Col1    g
 0   0.5  0.0
 1   0.3  0.0
 2   1.0  0.0
 3   3.0  0.0,    Col1    g
 4   0.2  1.0
 5   3.0  1.0
 6   3.0  1.0,    Col1    g
 7   4.0  2.0,    Col1    g
 8   5.0  3.0]
```